# Grunt connect task and middleware Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I would like to allow access to cross origin calls which I need to be able to perform rest API calls to the server.

My connect grunt task is configured as follows:

```
    connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729,
    middleware: function(connect, options, next) {
      return [
        function(req, res, next) {
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
          next();
        }
      ];
    }
  },
},
```

When I run the grunt server I am getting `Cannot GET /`.
Without the middleware configuration the app is working and the index file is loaded correctly.

Could you guide me to what I am doing wrong or missing out?

Some more details about my gruntfile is that I am using the yeoman angular seed app as my base to the app.

Comment: I don't think the middleware function takes a "next" parameter.

Comment: Yes, the line above should be: middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares).  https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#middleware, second example under middlewares.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729,

    // remove next from params
    middleware: function(connect, options) {
      return [
        function(req, res, next) {
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
          res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

          // don't just call next() return it
          return next();
        },

        // add other middlewares here 
        connect.static(require('path').resolve('.'))

      ];
    }
    },
    },
```

Comment: I just tried your change but I am still not able to get the app to work. Some more details about my gruntfile is that I am using the yeoman angular seed app as my base to the app.

Comment: If you are using yeoman you shuld add something like this to your middleware: ```connect.static(require('path').resolve(yeomanConfig.app));```

Comment: This still gives me "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" in firebug. What needs to be done besides the settings above to get CORS working?

Answer (score 2):

Nod to bpaul, who set me on the path to correct answer.  The format of a response to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992931/grunt-contrib-connect-middleware-cors-solution-with-keepalive-true) will work here.

Replace 'next' with middlewares, and push your anonymous function into the middleware array before returning it:

```
middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {

    middlewares.unshift(function(req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
        next();
    });

    return middlewares;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I like this way of doing middleware more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729,
    middleware: function(connect, options, next) {
      return [
        function(req, res, next) {
         res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
         res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
         res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
         next();
      }];
     }
   };
```

this will helps you in getting the get call Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Comment: Tried the changes but still no luck .. don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: The above will throw an error because res doesn't have a header method. You need to use res.setHeader.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt connect comes with multiple middlewares, stored as functions in an array. When you set middleware by returning an array, you override the existing middleware responsible for serving your pages.

Going off ansorensen's comment of the documentation, https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#middleware the relevant section being.

```
options: {
    middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
      // inject a custom middleware into the array of default middlewares
      middlewares.unshift(function(req, res, next) {
        if (req.url !== '/hello/world') return next();

        res.end('Hello, world from port #' + options.port + '!');
      });

      return middlewares;
    },
},
```

Middleware earlier in the array take effect before those later in the array.

So what you would want is

```
connect: {
    options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729,

        // remove next from params
        middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
            middlewares.unshift(function(req, res, next) {
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

                return next();
            });

            return middlewares;
        }
    },
},
```