# grunt-contrib-connect middleware CORS solution with keepalive true

Tags: cors, grunt-contrib-connect

For my local development system I am trying to serve front-end assets using grunt-contrib-connect. I need a cross-domain solution for using fonts in Firefox. The server runs just fine, but I cannot seem to get the headers set.

I am using version 0.7.1 of grunt-contrib-connect.

```
connect: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                port: '9001',
                base: 'build',
                hostname: 'localhost',
                keepalive: true,
                middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
                    // inject a custom middleware into the array of default middlewares
                    // this is likely the easiest way for other grunt plugins to
                    // extend the behavior of grunt-contrib-connect
                    middlewares.push(function(req, res, next) {
                        req.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                        req.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
                        return next();
                    });

                    return middlewares;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Is there a problem using keepalive with middleware?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's sad that nobody responded to that earlier.

Your code looks just like in the documentation, but you add the headers to `req` instead of `res`.

The second problem is <del>that the docs mislead you into</del>[(fixed)](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect/issues/114#event-145223615) adding your middleware with `.push`. Your code is not called at all, because something before it is doing a `res.end` and/or not calling `next()`.

Your fixed code would look like this:

```
    middleware: function (connect, options, middlewares) {
                    // inject a custom middleware 
                    middlewares.unshift(function (req, res, next) {
                        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
                        //a console.log('foo') here is helpful to see if it runs
                        return next();
                    });

                    return middlewares;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks! I never would have figured this out if not for your issue. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect/issues/114

Comment: It's confusing. I debugged it and had to guess what happens :| Glad I helped!