# Grunt Connect can't get CORS to work

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I'm trying to allow cors on grunt connect task that hosts the angular app. *I'm using angular yeoman generator. Here is what i've tried so far:

```
  connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9004,
            hostname: 'localhost',
            livereload: 35728,
            middleware: function(connect, options) {
                return [
                    function(req, res, next) {
                        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
                        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
                        return next();
                    },
                    connect.static(require('path').resolve(yeomanConfig.app))
                ];
            }
        },
```

When i load localhost:9004 i want to have access-control-allow-origin:*  in headers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grunt connect task and middleware Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581258/grunt-connect-task-and-middleware-access-control-allow-origin)